# why are functions defined inside play framework template not allowed to state return type?

Tags: playframework-2.0

the following inside a play framework template works fine:

```
@cdnPath(productID: String) = @{

   "http://www.mydomain.com/" + productID + ".png"

}
```

but the following - with the return type explicitly stated does not work:

```
@cdnPath(productID: String):String = @{

   "http://www.mydomain.com/" + productID + ".png"

}
```

I am curious why this is so? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not part of template parser spec. We have a new template compiler at works which will fix some of these issues.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/templates-compiler/src/main/scala/play/templates/ScalaTemplateCompiler.scala#L343